# Multi level defaults write value as integer instead of string

Tags: defaults, domain

From [macOS defaults write -data](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/423115/macos-defaults-write-data/441755)

I'm looking to add as above.

Basically, trying to achieve https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7591084#updatepolicysettings&zippy=%2Cturn-off-updates%2Csample-property-list

I managed to add it like `defaults write /Users/samson/Library/Preferences/com.google.Keystone.Agent.plist '{"updatePolicies" = {global = {UpdateDefault = 4;};};}'`

But the value 4 adds it as a string instead of integer like below.

```
<key>updatePolicies</key>
<dict>
  <key>global</key>
  <dict>
    <key>UpdateDefault</key>
    <string>3</string>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

How do I add it as an integer instead ?

Also, this erases the existing plist contents and adds only what I added in above command? How do I add the above, in addition to what is already in the plist ?

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: TBH, the defaults command isn't very good at complex dicts. I would just edit it in a text editor.

Comment: Well yeah :D I'm looking to deploy this for everyone in our company. Configuration profile is not an option for now as they are separate from our MDM ones. So, I'm just trying to deploy this as part of outset (kinda like loginhook), to run this as a script.